# Function to assign names to multiple list elements

Tags: r, list, names

I have a list of data frames `int1` and `int2`. The end goal of this code is to assign the names to the elements in `int1` and `int2`. The rest of the workflow for my work requires me to name the elements of the list multiple times, and I was wondering how I could create a function to reduce the number of keystrokes down the line using base r functions. Any ideas?

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2011"), dmy("31-07-2011"), by = "days"), 200)
ID <- rep(c("A","B", "C"), 200)
df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df$Month <- month(df$date)

# Create first list
int1 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "1") %>% 
  group_split()

# Create second list
int2 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "2") %>% 
  group_split()

# Expected Output

# Assign names to int1
names(int1) <- sapply(int1, function(x) paste(x$ID[1],
                                              x$new[1], sep = "_"))
# Assign names to int2
names(int2) <- sapply(int2, function(x) paste(x$ID[1],
                                              x$new[1], sep = "_"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `group_split` will not name the `list` elements.  It is specified in the `?group_split`

> it does not name the elements of the list based on the grouping as this typically loses information and is confusing.

Instead use `split` from `base R`, which will return with the names `paste`ed using `.` from the 'ID', 'new' columns

```
int1 <- df %>%
  # arrange(ID) %>%   # skipped for readability of result
  mutate(new = floor_date(date, '10 day')) %>%
  mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, new) %>%
  filter(Month == "1") %>% ungroup %>% 
  {split(., .[c('ID', 'new')])}
```

Similarly for `int2`